# Как создать триггер?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Даны две таблицы: `Инструменты` и `Поступление` на склад. Надо создать триггер, изменяющий значение поля `Инструменты`. Количество при заполнении `Поступление_на_склад.Количество`.

Comment: Вы бы написали о каком СУБД идет речь. Синтаксис триггеров везде разный. А где-то их вообще нет...

Answer (score 1):

Для MS SQL

```
create trigger <trigger_name>
on Поступление_на_склад
after insert
as
begin
update Инструменты
set Инструменты.Количество = Инструменты.Количество + inserted.Количетсво
where Инструменты.КодТовара = inserted.КодТовара
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER пост_на_склад AFTER INSERT ON Поступление
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO склад SET кол-во = кол-во + NEW.кол-во where склад.кодтовара = NEW.кодтовара;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html